# how to preform jquery http post req in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, http

I want to post a single string to my controller from the view.
The string is the name of a website.

on the view, the the users clicks a website's name , I want to render info based on the clicked website name.

my view(note all websites render 100%)

```
<h1>My Websites</h1>
@{
    foreach (var website in Model.websites)
    {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>  <a  class="websiteLink" href="">@website </a> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    }
}
```

MVC action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getWebsiteName(string webiste)
{
   
    //return partial view here
    return RedirectToAction("WebsiteOptions", "Home");
}
```

js:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.websiteLink').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        var websiteName = item.innerHTML;
        $.post("/Home/getWebsiteName", { WebsiteName: websiteName }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        //alert(WebsiteName);
    });
});
```

when I do the alert function to test it works fine, the correct website name is shown when clicked, I just want to post the clicked website name to my controller but it's not working :( nothing happens in the action yet because it does not work.. I've set e breakpoint there to test if the parameter is correct

Comment: Your parameter names need to match.  `webiste` does not match `WebsiteName`.  The action should still get called, but `webiste` will be null - is that the case?

Comment: **Always** add an ajax error handler.  In this case:  `$.post(...).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus, errorThrown) })`

Comment: hi @freedomn-m , no tht is not the case it is not evennull... it never gets called

Comment: And what's the error?  I'm assuming your `$.post` line *is* called?  Add an error handler and check the network tab.  eg if it's a 404 then your url is incorrect, eg your Action is not in the Home controller.

Comment: @freedomn-m i have added error handling in the post req, bu don't get anything back? its like the post call never gets run?

Comment: $.post("/Home/getWebsiteName", { WebsiteName: websiteName }, function (data, status) {

                        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    })

Comment: Trying to set a redirect  as the response to an AJAX call doesn't make much sense. The whole purpose of AJAX is to allow you to stay on the same page! It would make more sense for the action to return some text or JSON, or something. Anyway, if you see no error in the console, check the Network tool in your browser, and make sure the request to /getWebsiteName is actually fired, and then see what result you get, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below solved my problem

```
document.querySelectorAll('.websiteLink').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {

            //storing clicked website name
            var websiteName = item.innerHTML;
            item.style.textDecoration  = "underline";
           


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("getWebsiteName")",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { WebsiteName: websiteName },

                    success: function (data) {

                        alert(data);
                    },
                    failure: function (errMsg) {

                        alert(errMsg);
                    }
                });


        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

your request is supposed to look like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.websiteLink').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        var websiteName = item.innerHTML;
        $.post("/Home/getWebsiteName?website=" + websiteName, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        //alert(WebsiteName);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nearly...notice the typo in OP's parameter name - they've got `webiste` rather than `website` :-)